# by.xpath not working despite being correct xpath

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pdf, xpath, webdriver

I'm trying to locate this title element after a pdf is loaded. I'm using `contains()`, as the .pdf name won't ever change, but depending on the app used to open the pdf, the start of it can change, so I need to capture a substring.

```html
...
</meta>
<title>
Notes - Learning.pdf
</title>
<!--This snippet is used in the Firefox extension (included from viewer.html)-->
...
```

Here's my code in Java to do that:

```java
String xpaths = "//*[contains(text(), 'Learning.pdf')]"
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpaths)));
```

I'm sure there's no problem with my xpaths string, as I've tried different ones like replacing `text()` with `.` or even trying to zone in on it and replacing the `*` with `title`. And they are all valid as when I paste the xpath in inspect element they return the correct element. I've noticed that when I leave the xpaths string empty it's able to process that and doesn't fail. But once I try any word or letter it fails to find it.

I've also noticed when I do `By.name("Notes - Learning.pdf")` it works and locates it. So it's not a problem with the driver but rather the xpath and perhaps the fact it's a pdf, which may make things trickier. But I thought By.name only searches for name attributes which this isn't, so that's confused me a bit.I've also tried extending the waiting time to 600 seconds, and it still can't find it.

Alternatively, feel free to let me know of any non-xpath solution to my current problem, which is trying to verify this pdf has opened across different apps by taking a substring.

Comment: Could we please get a [mcve]?

Comment: a Title is not visible in the DOM. Don't use visibilityOf...

Comment: I think you can use ExpectedConditions.titleContains: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#titleContains(java.lang.String)   It'll return a bool.

Comment: for some reason when I try to get use functions like driver.getpagesource or driver.gettitle or the one you posted, it gives me unsupported command error

Comment: try:  Boolean doespass  =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains('Learning.pdf'));

Comment: btw, if this is a PDF file and not a web page, Selenium won't be able to interact with it.   The only Selenium command that will work would be another .get().  If the PDF is in an <EMBED> tag inside the page, you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath expression was missing a closing bracket (`]`).

Use this:

`"//*[contains(text(), 'Learning.pdf')]"`

OR

`"//*[contains(., 'Learning.pdf')]"`

Comment: Ah that was a mistake on my question. In the code i've got a closed bracket so it's not that. The error is specifically that It can't find the element.

Comment: Try `"//*[contains(., 'Learning.pdf')]"` as the xpath. I just updated my solution.

Comment: Yup i've tried that as well. Still nothing. It's definitely not the xpath string, as when I paste all these that i've tried in inspect element they work. I added some surrounding html in the question, in case that helps

Answer (score 0):

`//*[contains(text(), 'Learning.pdf')]` is very tricky because it will raise most certainly an error.
When there are elements with more than one text()-node the contains-function will fail because the first argument of the contains-function accepts **one** string.

Therefore you should use one of the following:

1. `//*[contains(., 'Learning.pdf')]` where the `.` concats all text-nodes to one string
2. `//*[contains[count(text())=1](text(), 'Learning.pdf')]` will only match those elements that only have one text-node
3. `//*[contains(text()[1], 'Learning.pdf')]` will match only those elements where the first text-node contains your search-string. Where `[1]` can be replaced by other numbers depending on the position of the text-node.

But since you tried the first option **something else is wrong**.